# Bootstrap margin left class is not working in react

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

Navbar

```
        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li className="nav-item active">
                    <a className="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li className="nav-item">
                    <a className="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>`
```

I am using bootstrap in my react project. Some of the class is not working properly. This class supposed to move all the nav li to the right, but it didn't

[image: This class supposed to move all the nav li to the right, but it didn't]

What could be the reason and how may I fix it?

[image: This is the output]

Comment: An image of code alone is generally considered insufficient for a post; could you please include a [mcve] of actual code-- preferably as a snippet-- that can be used to help the community provide you with meaningful guidance?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your assistance. I have added a code snippet. Please let me know if that is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your `nav` content under the `.container-fluid` element, as it is fluid by default.

```
<nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-dark">
    <div className="container-fluid">
    ...
    </div>
</nav>
```